# C++ | Need Help Transitioning From A For Loop Function -> a Recursive Function

Tags: c++, for-loop, recursion, iteration

So for one of my homework assignments we were asked to create a hailstonesequence and I'm completely stuck.  I have a hard time figuring out how to break down segments of a function containing loops, and then trying to essentially translate it into a recursive function.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Down below I have the original for-loop function, and then the (Attempted) recursive function.

```
// startingValue function with For-Loop
// Takes in an int value n and returns the
// start value k from 1 to n, that has the longest length.

int startingValue (int n) {
    int length = 0;
    int k;

    for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ ) {
        int currentLength = largestHailstoneLength(i);

        if (currentLength > length) {
            length = currentLength;
            k = i;
        }
    }       

    return k;
}
```

Here's my attempt for a recursive version of the function above:

```
int startingValue (int n) {
    int length = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int currentLength = largestHailstoneLength(i);

    if (currentLength < length) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        length = currentLength;
        n = i;
    }

    return (startingValue(i));
}
```

Comment: Tidy up this code with some identation.

Comment: Alright, added indentation.

Comment: I don't know what's your definition of well indented code, but you should revise that a bit, it might help you getting more answer here, and certainly a more maintainable code. I made proper formatting to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something simple, and probably inefficient, that should get you started:

```
int startingValue(int n) {

    if (n == 1) {
        return n;
    }

    int m = startingValue(n - 1);

    return largestHailstoneLength(n) > largestHailstoneLength(m) ? n : m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to do your homework, but I'll show you what a solution looks like in Ruby, a language that's about as readable as pseudo-code.  Anything after a `#` is a comment.

```
# Ruby equivalent to your C++ loop version
def start(n)
  biggest = 0
  k = -1
  (1..n).each do |i|  # loop from 1 to n, inclusive...
    # don't have access to your largestHailstoneLength(i) function,
    # so I'm using a random number on the range [0,1000)
    current = rand(1000)
    biggest, k = current, i if current > biggest
  end
  return k
end

# Using default argument values.  Alternatively, you can build
# a single-argument front end function and a recursive back end
# with these args the state info.
def start_recursive(n, i = 1, biggest = 0, k = -1)
  current = rand(1000)  # same as above
  biggest, k = current, i if current > biggest
  return i < n ? start_recursive(n, i + 1, biggest, k) : k
end

srand 12345  # explicit seed to RNG for reproducibility of sequence
p start(1000)  # => 301
srand 12345  # reseed RNG sequence to show recursive version yields same result
p start_recursive(1000)  # => 301
```

---

### ADDENDUM

After thinking about it a bit, and playing with larger ranges, I came up with the following variant which is much less likely to suffer from stack overflow—it uses a divide and conquer strategy to partition the range of candidates.  I've also replaced the random number evaluation with a call to your `largestHailstoneLength(i)`:

```
def start_recursive(upper_index, lower_index = 1)
  return lower_index if lower_index >= upper_index
  mid = (lower_index + upper_index) / 2
  lower_max = start_recursive(mid, lower_index)
  upper_max = start_recursive(upper_index, mid + 1)
  if largestHailstoneLength(lower_max) < largestHailstoneLength(upper_max)
    return upper_max
  else
    return lower_max
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in your code

1. You don't define `i` inside your recursive function
2. You don't seem to have a clue on how recursion works, I'll give you a clue:

   - Each time you call a function, you save a state.
   - You need to state where your recursive function stops, or it will keep calling itself until it crashes with stack overflow.
   - You need to know whether you wan't to work with what is returned by the function or if you want to work with what you're passing to it (or both)

If I got it right, `startingValue()` should return a value to which `largestHailstoneLength()` is the greatest possible.

So what we follow here is an induction principle:

- I have `n` values
- If `n` is `1`, i don't have to run any comparisons, just return `n`.

Otherwise

- If `n` is the greatest, it should be greater than the greatest between `1` and `n - 1`.
- Now we need to see the greatest between `1` and `n - 1`.
- If `n - 1` is the greatest, it should be greater than the greatest between `1` and `n - 2`
- ...

Well then, the fisrt thing to do is check for `n`

```
// Stop here, no need to go compare
if (n == 1) return n;
```

What we need to do inside the recursion is to compare the *current* `n` with the greatest from `1` to `n - 1`. that is:

```
// If current n is greater then the best case for n - 1
int k = startingValue(n - 1);
if (largestHailstoneLength(n) > largestHailstoneLength(k))
{
    // n is greater
}
else // startingValue(n - 1) is greater
```

Knowing which is the greater one, we simply return it.

To understand things better, read a little bit more. You can begin [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29).